# main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for

Tags: magento2, error, blocks, magento2.3, slider

if we do any modifications or if we add any image in tm_slider block and click on save button it is taking much time and getting 504 gateway time error and website is also not working 10 t0 15 mins at this time and when i check in system log i am getting below errors

> [2019-05-28 16:15:33] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/5percentoffer.png' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:33] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/5percentoffer.png' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:33] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/banner5.png' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:33] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/banner5.png' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:36] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/main-banner.jpg' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:36] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/main-banner.jpg' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:38] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/5percentoffer.png' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:38] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/5percentoffer.png' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:41] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/banner2.jpg' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:41] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/banner2.jpg' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:41] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/banner2.jpg' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:41] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/banner2.jpg' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:42] main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/banner5.png' [] []
>   [2019-05-28 16:15:42] main.CRITICAL: Unable to resolve the source file
>   for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/images/banner5.png' [] []

Comment: are you able to resolve that issue ?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj Not solved